# getting multi row data into columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT 
  Day, 
  month, 
  year,
  GROUP_CONCAT(total), 
  GROUP_CONCAT(SP_ID)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      DATE_FORMAT(l.act_date, '%d') AS DAY, 
      DATE_FORMAT(l.act_date, '%M') AS MONTH,
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM l.act_date) AS YEAR, 
      COUNT(*) as total,l.sp_id 
    FROM lead_activity2 as l
    right outer join salesperson as s on l.sp_id=s.sp_id
    WHERE l.act_name='scb' 
      AND ((l.act_date>='2012-09-07 13:03:27' ) 
      AND (l.act_date<= '2012-11-07 13:03:27')) 
    GROUP BY MONTH, YEAR, DAY, l.sp_id 
    ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTH DESC, DAY DESC, l.sp_id DESC
) t GROUP BY day, month, year
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1514d/3 - you can view the scheme and the query,

what i would like to get is

```
18 | october | 2012 | 0,0,1,1 | 6,5,4,3
```

spid 6 and spid 5 have no data for 18 october but still should be shown tried doing right join and right outer join both dont seem to work...

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(total, 0))` to get `0` for rows with no matching data in the outer join.

Comment: @barmer can you write the query and show it ... i tired putting an outer join ... " outer join salesperson as s on l.sp_id=s.sp_id" and it gives an error

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like so:

```
SELECT 
  Day, 
  month, 
  year,
  GROUP_CONCAT(total), 
  GROUP_CONCAT(SP_ID)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      DATE_FORMAT(l.act_date, '%d') AS DAY, 
      DATE_FORMAT(l.act_date, '%M') AS MONTH,
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM l.act_date) AS YEAR, 
      COUNT(*) as total,l.sp_id 
    FROM lead_activity2 as l 
    WHERE l.act_name='scb' 
      AND ((l.act_date>='2012-09-07 13:03:27' ) 
      AND (l.act_date<= '2012-11-07 13:03:27')) 
    GROUP BY MONTH, YEAR, DAY, l.sp_id 
    ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTH DESC, DAY DESC, l.sp_id DESC
) t GROUP BY day, month, year
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5aff7/3)

**Update:** Yes you can do this, but use `LEFT JOIN` to include non matching `sp_id`. These non matching ids will have a value of `NULL` use `IFNULL` to display it with zeros like so:

```
SELECT 
  Day, 
  month, 
  year,
  GROUP_CONCAT(total) Total, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(SP_ID) 'List of sp_ids'
FROM
(
  SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(l.act_date, '%d') AS DAY, 
    DATE_FORMAT(l.act_date, '%M') AS MONTH, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM l.act_date) AS YEAR, 
    COUNT(*) as total,
    IFNULL(s.sp_id , 0) sp_id
  FROM lead_activity2 as l 
  LEFT JOIN salesperson s ON l.sp_id = s.sp_id
  WHERE l.act_name='scb' 
    AND ((l.act_date>='2012-09-07 13:03:27' )
    AND (l.act_date<= '2012-11-07 13:03:27')) 
  GROUP BY MONTH, YEAR,DAY,s.sp_id 
) t
ORDER BY YEAR DESC, 
         MONTH DESC, 
         DAY DESC, 
         sp_id DESC
```

### [Updates SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0438d/8)

Comment: this works.... however just wanted to know if i had a join statement to another table which contained details of sp_id ...and say i had 5 different sp_id in that table... how can the query be modified ...to add the sp_id's that not match / get hit on the above query and add a 0 for example 

18 | october | 2012 | 0,1,1,0,0 | 5,4,3,2,1

Comment: hey the result is a bit off it should give lal dates for SCB and lal the users including null...